# Get values from other sheet based on other cell values

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

How to get values from another sheet if another cell empty. I'm trying to get values from sheet1 column B if in sheet1 column H empty.

I mean if Sheet1 column B2 to B4 have values and in Column H on the same sheet, if  H2 and H3 have text only B4 value print.

Sheet1 Image

[image]

Sheet2 Image

[image]

Here is what I try to do that not work

```
=query(Sheet1!B2:B, "Select Sheet1!b where Sheet1!H <> ''")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=FILTER(Sheet1!B2:B, Sheet1!B2:B<>"", Sheet1!C2:C="")
```

or:

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!B2:C, "select B where B is not null and C is null", 0)
```

or:

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!B2:C, "select B where B !='' and C =''", 0)
```

Comment: Hi, can you please tell me  can we use this with =IMPORTRANGE formula or any other way to do the same thing with =IMPORTRANGE

Comment: sure, `=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("ID", "Sheet1!B2:C"), "select Col2 where Col2 !='' and Col3 =''", 0)`